# What are pros and cons of gwt? And why should I should choose it to use?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I am still a beginner in GWT. I want to know preferable features of GWT rather than other frameworks.

 And has there any advantages or disadvantages on using GWT ?

I asked this question due to below external links...

1. [Pros and Cons of Google Web Toolkit, Part I](http://thoughtfulsoftware.blogspot.com/2013/03/pros-and-cons-of-google-web-toolkit.html)
2. [Pros and Cons of Google Web Toolkit, Part 2](http://thoughtfulsoftware.blogspot.com/2013/03/pros-and-cons-of-google-web-toolkit_23.html)
3. [The disadvantages of the Google Web Toolkit](http://confusion.tweakblogs.net/blog/1052/the-disadvantages-of-the-google-web-toolkit.html)
4. [GWT Development Advantages/Disadvantages](http://dantuscoffeetime.blogspot.com/2011/07/gwt-development-advantagesdisadvantages.html)
5. [Pros and Cons of GWT](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-18969.html)
6. [Why Google Web Toolkit (GWT)?](http://bear-z.com/gwt/why-google-web-toolkit-gwt/)
7. [Advantages and Disadvantages of GWT (Google Web Toolkit)](http://ercillatechnologies.blogspot.com/2010/01/disadvantages-of-google-web-toolkit.html)

Yes , I know there has many relative informations on above links . I understand that there has no completed frameworks ever. I should choose frameworks for my project demand. So , please assume this question as a discussion . But I am sure it is not really [opnion base question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

 There have many experience users with [GWT on **SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gwt/info) . I want to get some useful discussions , suggestions or informations from them.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery vs Google Closure va GWT Pros & cons for large web application development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455435/jquery-vs-google-closure-va-gwt-pros-cons-for-large-web-application-developmen)

Comment: He explain some little things. about History , rpc , reuseable , easy to test. But I want to know more.

Comment: Have also a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99866/biggest-gwt-pitfalls) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097964/why-gwt-advantages-and-trade-offs-of-using-this-ria-framework).

Comment: Html 5 is made easy with Java. Canvas support and MVP pattern are all pluses for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Advantages**

- If you are familiar with java. There will be no learning curve
- Code can be reusable + all the facilities come along with java
- When the application becomes larger the code will be easy to maintain
- Handle the browser compatibility

**Disadvantages**

- Need lot of memory to run it in dev mode
- High compile time
- Every server call will be ajax
- You will loose control on your javascript

That's all i can think of now :-). Find more in http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/gwt-pros-and-cons.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I hate the time of browsers downloading time of javascript files :) . But as your mention , when the application becomes larger the code will be easy to maintain. That is useful fact for me.